# How to keep remote MariaDB schema synced with local

Tags: database, synchronization, mariadb

I am developing a MariaDB database for my website and it sees daily many changes to column names, data types, triggers, events and routines.

How do I keep the entire schema synced, to allow peaceful deployment of new website code?

Of course it is vital to keep remote data intact (only sync the schema) and preferably reduce downtime to minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Use replication.

Be aware that it could be harmful to replicate `TRIGGERs` -- The Primary runs the trigger, which inserts a new row.  If the Replica also runs the trigger and creates another row, now you have an extra row (or an error) on the Replica.

Answer (score 0):

If your web application code requires database changes, you need a library to write migrations for your database. When deploying the new website code, you must run the migration code : deploy the migration code, and execute the migration.

For instance, you could write your migrations using [phinx](https://github.com/cakephp/phinx) if you code in php already, but there are [other options](https://github.com/lulco/phoenix), some might be linked to your [framework, doctrine for instance](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/migrations.html) .

You can ship your migration code with your website code, the deployment would look like : deploy the code, stop the server, execute the migration, restart the server.

If you want no downtime, then your website code must be able to run on both versions of the database : before and after the migration (you can check the database version on each function using the database to check the current version).

Some `ALTER` would still lock the database to make some changes. You can use some tools to avoid this :

- some recent versions of mariadb have some built in [ONLINE DDL](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-online-ddl-overview/)
- [pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-online-schema-change.html) can be used to avoid downtime when doing some `ALTER` too
- [gh-ost](https://github.com/github/gh-ost) can be used if you already have a replication mecanism (used by github)
- [Large Hadron Migrator](https://github.com/soundcloud/lhm) could be used, ([there is an integration in phinx](https://github.com/masom/lhm_php), and some [other solutions listed at the bottom](https://github.com/soundcloud/lhm#similar-solutions))

[A nice presentation about ONLINE DDL, pt-online-schema-change and gh-ost](https://www.percona.com/live/18/sessions/mysql-schema-migrations-exploring-the-options)

If you have a cluster of web servers, and a cluster of databases, things might be more complicated, and gh-ost seems like the only option from what I have seen so far, but if you are asking this question, I guess you have one web server, and one database, and just writing some scripts and keeping track of your database version (to avoid running twice the same migration) should be fine.

You should test your migration code, before deploying it on your production server, to avoid unexpected behaviour, same as every code you write anyway.